# NullPointerException when writing csv file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, opencsv

I want to write a csv with the `opencsv` libary, however, when running the code I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
public void exportToCSV(ArrayList<Data> list) throws IOException {
        log.info("write CSV file");

        String writerPath = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Output\\output.csv";

        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(writerPath), ';');

        //headers
                String [] entries = {"ID", "Date"};

        writer.writeNext(entries);

        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for (int m = 0; m < list.size(); m++) {
            data.add(new String[] {
                    list.get(m).getID,
                    (list.get(m).getDate().toString()==null) ? "null" : list.get(m).getDate().toString(), //Here i get the NullPointerException
            });
        }
        writer.writeAll(data);
        writer.close();
    }
```

I guess that `getDate()` is null, which type is a `Timestamp`. However, why does my proposed solution not work in writing a `String` when `getDate()` is `null`.

I apprecaite your reply!

Comment: why you "guess". in which line was the exception thrown? did you use a debugger to see what is actually null?

Comment: Because is getDate() returns null, you can't call toString() on it. Duh.

Comment: See also [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), where almost the very first line of the documentation is "Calling the instance method of a null object."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.get(m).getDate().toString()==null` should be changed to `list.get(m).getDate()==null`.

If `list.get(m).getDate()` is `null`. Invoking a method on it will cause `NullPointerException`.